# How can I make sure my random number between 0 and 1 generated by rand is not 0?

Tags: c++, random

I'm working on simulating a queuing model and I need to generate my arrivals using this algorithm. However I sometimes get 0.000000 as a random value R1 and it is not possible to calculate ln(0) therefore the process stops. How can I avoid getting a 0?

I thought about adding 0.0000001 to each, but wouldn't that be bad too because I might get something greater than 1?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

main()
    {
        int a=3, b=4, T=500, I=0, l=1504;
        srand(time(NULL));
        float R1, R2, t=0, S[10000], f;

        printf("Utilizaremos la funcion at+b para el simular el poceso\n");
        while(t<T){
            R1=rand()/(double)RAND_MAX;
            t= t-log(R1)/l;
            R2=rand()/(double)RAND_MAX;
            f = a*t+b;
            if(R2<f/l){
                I=I+1;
                S[I]=t;
                printf(" \n I %d, R1 %f, R2 %f, t %f, S[i] %f", I,R1,R2,t,S[I]);
            }


        }
        getche();
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if you just get another random number if you get 0? Also you should use [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) instead of `rand()` in C++. And if this is actually C (which it looks like), update the tags please.

Comment: rand() Considered Harmful - Stephan T. Lavavej  https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful

Answer (score 2):

Not that `rand()` is a good thing, but efficiently avoiding zero is easy:

```
double nzrand() {
  constexpr double max=RAND_MAX+1.;
  return (rand()+1.)/max;
}
```

This can return exactly 1; use `+2.` to avoid that, of course.

Of course, the more common approach is to generate random values on [0,1) (here, by adding 1 to the denominator but *not* the numerator) and compute `log(1-x)`.

Comment: If `rand()` can return `INT_MAX` this can overflow. You should add `1.0` to `rand()` instead of `1`.

Comment: @Kevin: Of course—I did it for `RAND_MAX` but not `rand()` itself.  Edited.

Answer (score 2):

Just get a random number until you don't get 0

```
double myrand()
{
    while(1)
    {
        double r = rand()/(double)RAND_MAX;
        if (r != 0)
            return r;
    }
}

...

R1 = myrand();  // Will not be 0
```

Answer (score 2):

The new and better way in C++ is to use the new [random number generator functionality](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) of the C++11 standard library

With [`uniform_real_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution) you can specify your range as `double` values like `(1e-12, 1.0)`. Or better yet use `(std::numeric_limits<double>::min(), 1.0)` which will give you the smallest `double` value that is not zero yet still normalized (`2.122e-314`).

Full example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    int a = 3, b = 4, T = 500, I = 0, l = 1504;
    std::random_device rndsource;
    std::minstd_rand rndgen(rndsource());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(1e-12, 1.0);
    double R1, R2, t = 0, S[10000], f;

    printf("Utilizaremos la funcion at+b para el simular el poceso\n");
    while (t < T) {
        R1 = dist(rndgen);
        t = t - log(R1) / l;
        R2 = dist(rndgen);
        f = a * t + b;
        if (R2 < f / l) {
            I = I + 1;
            S[I] = t;
            printf(" I %d, R1 %f, R2 %f, t %f, S[i] %f\n", I, R1, R2, t, S[I]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`std::minstd_rand` is an LCG, which is very fast and usable in most scientific applications. For better unpredictability, try the `std::mt19937` PRNG instead.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two simple ways.

1. Generate a number in [0,1) and subtract from 1:

   ```
   R1 = rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0);
   R1 = 1.0 - R1;
   ```
2. Add 1 to the result of rand() and increase the divisor correspondingly:

   ```
   R1 = (rand() + 1.0) / (RAND_MAX + 1.0);
   ```

Both result in a number in (0,1].

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is the right answer.

- First, you should use C++11  facilities (or, if you're using C++03, similar BOOST random library).
- Second, default double random number generation requires at least 53 random bits of mantissa, thus better use 64bit bitstream generator (mt19937_64 in example below). Thus one call to rng will produce one double, and typically would be faster on 64bit platform.
- Third, default uniform doubles generator produces numbers in the strict [0...1) range. Use 1-R trick to push it into (0...1] range.
- Fourth,your code have a bug - easy to overflow array S size with memory corruption as a result, I've added proper guard.
- Last - please do not use random_device as other people suggested. In general, you need fully reproducible runs, so seed better be controlled.

Code, Visual C++2019, Win10 x64

```
#include <cmath>
#include <random>
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    int a = 3, b = 4, T = 500, I = 0, l = 1504;

    double R1, R2, t = 0, S[10000], f;

    std::mt19937_64 rng{ 7719716254321ULL }; // init with known seed - reproducability
                                             // no need in random device
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> rnd{};

    printf("Utilizaremos la funcion at+b para el simular el poceso\n");
    while (t < T) {
        R1 = rnd(rng);
        t = t - log(1.0 - R1) / l;
        R2 = rnd(rng);
        f = a * t + b;
        if (R2 < f / l) {
            S[I] = t;
            printf(" I %d, R1 %f, R2 %f, t %f, S[i] %f\n", I, R1, R2, t, S[I]);
            ++I;
            if (I == sizeof(S) / sizeof(S[0]))
                break;
        }
    }
    (void)getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And here is yet another possibility:

```
double increment = 0.000000001;  // However small you need.
double near_zero = 0.005;
...

double nzrand() {

  double nzr = rand()/(double)RAND_MAX;
  if (nzr < near_zero) {
    nzr += increment;
  }
  return nzr;

} // end nzrand()
```

This only adds the small increment if the initial value is well short of 1.0, so it will never exceed one.  It will never return zero, the smallest possible return value is the given increment.